# How to generate a source map for minified CSS generated by dotless

Tags: css, source-maps, dotless

I'm using dotless to generate a minified CSS file via pre-build task.

Now i wonder how to create an appropriate .css.map file for that minified CSS file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dotless doesn't currently have support for generating map files. [See Here](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/pull/295#issuecomment-82754854)

`.map` files are usually generated on the creation of the minified file due to having to match up perfectly.

Your best option for generating a `.map` file would be to compile whatever CSS you have in the normal less compiler and copy it across to your project.

Less Command Line: [Documenation](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage)

The above documenation shows about command line usage and also, if you scroll down to the options it will give you information regarding source maps etc.

Comment: Hmmm, that's what i almost figured as i found that link too. Is there any command line tool being able to create a minified css + source map?

Comment: Oh my, why didn't i look at the original project in the first place, my bad. Giving it a try immediately...

Comment: Ok, using lessc seems too complicated for me right now as it introduces another dependency (npm). I just have to wait for source map support in dotless i guess.